# XMLHTTPREQUEST Keeps Returning Empty Line When I Send A Request

Tags: javascript, html, rest, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a login function where it filters through the rest api. The API itself works on localhost and when I enter the local host address(http://localhost:3000/config/username) myself in a browser it works completely fine, but when I try to access it via XMLHTTPREQUEST it keeps returning an empty line. I have tried many things, but it either returns undefined, null, a CORS error, or just doesn't do anything at all.

My Javascript Code Is:

```
async function getLogin(){
  console.log('------')
  let usernameElement = document.querySelector('#username')
  let passwordElement = document.querySelector('#password')
  const url = `http://localhost:3000/config/${usernameElement.value}`
  try {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    let jsonResponse;
    request.send()
    request.onload = function(){
      jsonResponse = request.response
    };
    alert(request.response)
  } catch(err){
    alert(err)
  }
}
```

And my html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
  <script src="scripts/login.js"></script>
  <title>Game Login</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="../tools/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="username" class="input" required>
        <label class="input-label">Username</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" class="input" required>
        <label class="input-label">Password</label>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" onclick="getLogin()" class="submit">
    </form>
  </section>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p>Don't have an account? Click here to register</p>
    <a href="register.html">REGISTER</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have been checking the documentation, looking at other questions in stack overflow and much more, but I can't seem to find an apparent answer to this.

**EDIT**

I managed to sort of get it to work, but now in order for the results to show, you have to ctrl click submit instead of click it regularly and I am completely confused as to why. One thing that I noticed was that every time you submit it adds this weird ? at the end of the url (eg: file:///filepath/index.html?) and I think that this is causing problems in some way but I don't know how. The current code I am using is

```
async function getLogin(){
  console.log('------')
  let usernameElement = document.querySelector('#username')
  let passwordElement = document.querySelector('#password')

  if (usernameElement.value == '' | passwordElement.value == '') {
    alert('Error, no username/password given');
    return;
  }
  const url = `http://localhost:3000/config/${usernameElement.value}`
  try {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    let jsonResponse;
    request.send()
    request.onload = function(){
      jsonResponse = request.response
      alert(request.response)
    };
  } catch(err){
    alert(err)
  }
}
```

Also I updated it so it now sends cors headers in my server.js file so now I am no longer getting cors errors. I am really confused as to why I have to ctrl click to get the alert, and about the extra question mark. If anyone has answers to this please tell me.

**FINAL EDIT**
After removing the form element and editing the css a bit, I made the website work on single click. And instead of form, I used a div tag and loaded a new page after getting the alert. It works and the question is closed.

Comment: does the server at `localhost:3000` send CORS headers (assuming `localhost:3000` is not the same server that serves the page, since you mentioned CORS I assume that is the case)

Comment: of course, `alert(request.response)` outside `onload` will be *blank* since `onload` has not been called yet

Comment: Ok so I put alert(request.response) inside of onload but now it doesn't do anything, and I'm guessing its because it never even loads

Comment: you mentioned CORS - is the request cross origin? does the server send CORS response headers? have you checked the browser developer tools to see what errors you have?

Comment: The request is not cross origin, it is simply getting it from localhost and I am not sure about the headers. How do I check? And yes I used the browser developer tools to check the errors, and currently I don't get any. In fact, it doesn't do anything at all other than refresh the page

Comment: Oh ... there's a `form` ... you know what happens when you submit a form? you load a new page

Comment: @JaromandaX Ik that check the updated question. And btw is that the reason for why you have to ctrl click because what that does is opens it in a new tab but continues doing what its doing in the original one? And how could I work around this?

Comment: `every time you submit it adds this weird ? at the end of the url` - because you're submitting a form

Comment: alright so at this point, in order for it to work you have to ctrl click the submit button, but I want to make it so you can just click it normally and it still works. I don't think the ? is a problem

Comment: `I don't think the ? is a problem` - no, it's a symptom of the problem - another problem is, you're trying to use XMLHttpRequest in page that is loaded using `file://` protocol - that won't work any more

Comment: Apparently after I deleted the form element and edited the css a little bit, it now works on single click. Thank you for all of the help and the comments

Comment: I did mention the button would "submit a form" yesterday